# Trying to use JOIN command in Google Sheets to omit parts of cell, is this possible?

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to take the contents of a cell that are numbered and join them together (separated by commas) and omit the numbers.  For example, cell A1 looks like this: 1.T,2.G,3.Y,4.S

Is it possible to join them into a different cell so it looks like this: T,G,Y,S

The numbers would be omitted leaving just the letters, separated with commas.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your example:

```
=regexreplace(A1,"\d.",)
```

`\d` is the Perl class of all digits. The RE2 removes any one of those that is followed by a dot.

Comment: Worked perfect! Thank you.  Can you explain how it works?

Comment: I am trying to use this command in a Google Script, but I am having a problem with the "\d." part.  It isn't adding the \ before the d. when it adds the formula when I run the script.  Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: UPDATE:  Fixed, all I had to do was add another \ to it in case anyone has the same problem.  So now it looks like"\\d."